# Merge with duplicate indices - Number rows greater than expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with some duplicate indices

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['I1', 'I1' ,'I1', 'I2', 'I2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=['D', 'E', 'F'], index=['I1', 'I1', 'I1', 'I2'])

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

It seems that pandas doesn't recognize that two indices have the same values
. I was expecting the dataframe to have to `5` rows with columns `A B C D E F`. With last row being all `nans` for  `D E F`

Something like this:

```
        A         B         C         D         E         F
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375  0.492218 -0.915034  1.667015
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375 -0.055575 -0.207215 -0.351027
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375  1.128143  1.371022  0.810542
I2 -0.817558  1.599293 -0.342841 -0.831796 -0.118316 -0.138027
I2 -0.817558  1.599293 -0.342841  NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Instead I get this:

```
          A         B         C         D         E         F
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375  0.492218 -0.915034  1.667015
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375 -0.055575 -0.207215 -0.351027
I1  0.121993  0.208368 -0.056375  1.128143  1.371022  0.810542
I1  0.403085  0.532958  0.856544  0.492218 -0.915034  1.667015
I1  0.403085  0.532958  0.856544 -0.055575 -0.207215 -0.351027
I1  0.403085  0.532958  0.856544  1.128143  1.371022  0.810542
I1  0.094214 -0.527932 -1.368606  0.492218 -0.915034  1.667015
I1  0.094214 -0.527932 -1.368606 -0.055575 -0.207215 -0.351027
I1  0.094214 -0.527932 -1.368606  1.128143  1.371022  0.810542
I2  0.378565  0.331995  0.167682 -0.831796 -0.118316 -0.138027
I2  0.378565  0.331995  0.167682 -0.561473 -0.898151 -0.217683
I2 -0.817558  1.599293 -0.342841 -0.831796 -0.118316 -0.138027
I2 -0.817558  1.599293 -0.342841 -0.561473 -0.898151 -0.217683
```

Edit: I cannot deduplicate the result since I do not want to lose duplicate rows in the original dataframes

Comment: You have the same index `I1` and `I2` repeated, it's correct? It's look a conbination of all possibility in data frame.

Comment: `pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The result looks like the result contain square of counts of each index. I want to preserve the same indices as the joining dataframes

Comment: @anky_91 `concat` is an `inner-join` I think. Ideally I would want a `left-join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) to join on same index:

```
pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1)

           A         B         C         D         E         F
I1  0.112906 -1.080809  0.857712 -0.849395  0.015475  0.619177
I1 -0.380070  1.389495  1.372172 -0.472603 -0.593138 -0.594146
I1 -0.258423  1.402873 -0.923191 -2.138440  0.099878  0.148920
I2 -1.618755 -0.459908 -0.803290 -0.267760  0.275084  0.810870
I2 -0.033210  0.523840 -1.028478 -1.300269 -1.516137  0.373555
```

**EDIT:**

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1).set_index(df1.index)

           A         B         C         D         E         F
I1  1.925637  0.082031  0.483414 -0.189940  0.763408 -0.346046
I1 -0.676511  0.482327  1.648381  2.635290 -0.080474  0.558633
I1  0.180004 -0.190909  0.821891 -1.010627  0.774914  0.988356
I2 -0.011089  0.364400 -0.207062 -1.335626  0.036884  1.628115
I2 -1.314910  0.294986  0.334418       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: This works in this particular case, however it wouldn't work if `count` of `I2` is `1`. I would want the  result to contain all `nans` in the final row in that case. 
Hence the attempted `left-join`

Comment: @Ajit fine, i will update my answer if you can provide some samples and expected output. :)